# Linked List Input and Output

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I want to create a program in C that differentiates between a number or a character and put them into a linked list, then output the list. The issue is that when I input anything into it, it only outputs 10. In the results down below 1+2+3, I need it to separate the char and the nums. Help will be greatly appreciated

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
 
 
// define a union to overlay an integer with a char
union DataType{
    int operand;
    char operate;
};
 
 
// typedef to rename DataType
typedef union DataType Data;
 
 
// create a structure for a node
typedef struct NodeType{
    Data data;
    struct NodeType* next;
}Node;
 
Node* top = NULL;
 
 
 
 
// typedef to rename NodeType
void displayNode();
 
void addNode() {
    Node * newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    char expression[64];
        // get the stuff
    printf("Enter expression: ");
    fgets(expression, 64, stdin);
    //char array , int size, stdin
 
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(expression); i++) { //checks individual character
 
        if (isdigit((expression[i]))){  // if digit add it to operate
 
            (*newNode).data.operate = (expression[i]); // how
        }else //else add it to operand
            newNode->data.operand = (expression[i]); //how
    }
    if (top == NULL)
        top = newNode;             // update headPtr in main
    else {
        Node *currPtr = top;
 
        // find last Node
        while (currPtr->next != NULL)
            currPtr = currPtr->next;
 
        // insert new Node
        currPtr->next = newNode;
    }
}
 
void popNode()
{
    if(top != NULL)
    {
        Node * temp = top;
        top = top->next;
        free(temp);
    }
}
 
 
void displayNode()
{
    if(top == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error");
        return;
    }
    Node * curr = top;
//    while(curr -> next != NULL){
        printf("\n+---------------------------------+");
        printf("\nOperator stack: ");
        printf("%c ", curr->data.operate);
 
 
        printf("\nOperand stack: ");
        printf("%d ", curr->data.operand);
        printf("\n+---------------------------------+");
 
        curr = curr->next;
//    }
}
 
 
int main()
{
    int menu = 1;
 
    do {
 
        //call an array in main
 
        addNode(&top);
 
        displayNode(&top);
 
        char cont;
        printf("\nDo you want to enter another expression (Y/N)?");
 
        scanf(" %c", &cont);
 
        if (cont == 'n'|| cont == 'N') { // if not close menu
            menu = 0;
        }
 
    }while(menu == 1);
    return 0;
}

Enter expression:1+2+3

+---------------------------------+
Operator stack:

Operand stack: 10
+---------------------------------+
Do you want to enter another expression (Y/N)?
```

Comment: Please make sure all information needed to answer your question is embedded in your question, not behind links. Secondly, *"neither works"* is not a good problem statement. Please select the code you want to ask about (one), explain what goes wrong, for which input, making sure it is reproducible.

Comment: Sorry, I will edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing out your code quickly indicated that the addNode function was only creating one initial node.  That is why you only see one operator stack output.  With that I moved the node creation line of code along with the node linkage loop inside the for loop.

Following is a revised version of your code with the noted changes in the addNode function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

// define a union to overlay an integer with a char
union DataType
{
    int operand;
    char operate;
};

// typedef to rename DataType
typedef union DataType Data;

// create a structure for a node
typedef struct NodeType
{
    Data data;
    struct NodeType* next;
} Node;

Node* top = NULL;

// typedef to rename NodeType
void displayNode();

void addNode()
{

    char expression[64];
    // get the stuff
    printf("Enter expression: ");
    fgets(expression, 64, stdin);
    //char array , int size, stdin

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(expression); i++)   //checks individual character
    {
        Node * newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));      /* Moved this line of code here to build multiple nodes */
        if (isdigit((expression[i])))   // if digit add it to operate
        {
            (*newNode).data.operate = (expression[i]); // how
        }
        else  //else add it to operand
            newNode->data.operand = (expression[i]); //how
        /* Moved this block of code inside the for loop to create the linked list */
        if (top == NULL)
            top = newNode;             // update headPtr in main
        else
        {
            Node *currPtr = top;

            // find last Node
            while (currPtr->next != NULL)
                currPtr = currPtr->next;

            // insert new Node
            currPtr->next = newNode;
        }
    }

}

void popNode()
{
    if(top != NULL)
    {
        Node * temp = top;
        top = top->next;
        free(temp);
    }
}

void displayNode()
{
    if(top == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error");
        return;
    }
    Node * curr = top;
    while(curr -> next != NULL){
        printf("\n+---------------------------------+");
        printf("\nOperator stack: ");
        printf("%c ", curr->data.operate);


        printf("\nOperand stack: ");
        printf("%d ", curr->data.operand);
        printf("\n+---------------------------------+");

    curr = curr->next;
    }
}


int main()
{
    int menu = 1;

    do
    {
        //call an array in main

        addNode();

        displayNode();

        char cont;
        printf("\nDo you want to enter another expression (Y/N)?");

        scanf(" %c", &cont);

        if (cont == 'n'|| cont == 'N')   // if not close menu
        {
            menu = 0;
        }

    }
    while(menu == 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Following was the output at the terminal utilizing your test expression.

```
@Dev:~/C_Programs/Console/Diff/bin/Release$ ./Diff 
Enter expression: 1+2+3

+---------------------------------+
Operator stack: 1 
Operand stack: 49 
+---------------------------------+
+---------------------------------+
Operator stack: + 
Operand stack: 43 
+---------------------------------+
+---------------------------------+
Operator stack: 2 
Operand stack: 50 
+---------------------------------+
+---------------------------------+
Operator stack: + 
Operand stack: 43 
+---------------------------------+
+---------------------------------+
Operator stack: 3 
Operand stack: 51 
+---------------------------------+
Do you want to enter another expression (Y/N)?
```

I suspect that there is some more refinement that you would probably do but this gets your code to the point of creating multiple nodes and linking them.  Give that a try and see if it meets the spirit of your project.

Comment: Hey! I tried putting this into my IDE and it does not output. I get the prompt "enter expression" but when i enter something it doesn't do anything. I didn't get any results.

i did
 Enter expression:
Enter expression:1+2+3
then nothing happens.

Comment: Not sure what to tell you.  Just to make sure, I copied the above code back into my IDE (Code::Blocks), recompiled it, launched the program, entered 1+2+3, and got the above output again.  FYI, I am using the gcc compiler and running on a Linux system.

Comment: huh i see, well i recopied it multiple times back into Clion, and its not outputting correctly :(
edit: hm i posted it on another ide and it output, interesting..

Comment: I'm not familiar with Clion but I am glad you got it to work.